# Running android Lint has encountered

Tags: android, adt

I updated by SDK tools and ADT, and after opening I found this error in my Eclipse.

[image: Screen shot of the error]

Comment: Try disabling lint check.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project  go to properties and click on android lint prefe and you have the option ignoreall click it after that click ok.....